# Supporting multiple versions of models for different REST API versions

Tags: backwards-compatibility, api-versioning

Are there any best practices for the implementation of API versioning? I'm interested in the following points:

1. Controller, service - e.g. do we use a different controller class for each version of the API? Does a newer controller class inherit the older controller?
2. Model - if the API versions carry different versions of the same model - how do we handle conversions? E.g. if v1 of the API uses v1 of the model, and v2 of the API uses v2 of the model, and we want to support both (for backward-compatibility) - how do we do the conversions?
3. Are there existing frameworks/libraries can I use for these purposes in Java and JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I always recommend a distinct controller class per API version. It keeps things clean and clear to maintainers. The next version can usually be started by *copying and pasting* the last version. You *should* define a clear versioning policy; for example *N-2* versions. By doing so, you end up with 3 side-by-side implementations rather than an explosion that some people think you'll have. Refactoring business logic and other components that are not specific to a HTTP API version out of controllers can help reduce code duplication.
2. In my strong opinion, a controller should **absolutely not** inherit from another controller, save for a base controller with version-neutral functionality (but not APIs). HTTP **is** the API. HTTP has **methods**, not verbs. Think of it as `Http.get()`. Using is another language such as Java, C#, etc is a facade that is an impedance mismatch to HTTP. HTTP does not support inheritance, so attempting to use inheritance in the implementation is only likely to exacerbate the mismatch problem. There are other practical challenges too. For example, you can *unherit* a method, which complicates the issue of sunsetting an API in inherited controllers (not all versions are additive). Debugging can also be confusing because you have to find the correct implementation to set a breakpoint. Putting some thought into a versioning policy and factoring responsibilities to other components will all, but negate the need for inheritance in my experience.
3. Model conversion is an implementation detail. It is solely up to the server. Supporting conversions is very situational. Conversions can be bidirectional (`v1<->v2`) or unidirectional (`v2->v1`). A *Mapper* is a fairly common way to convert one form to another. Additive attribute scenarios often just require a default value for new attributes in storage for older API versions. Ultimately, there is no single answer to this problem for all scenarios.
4. It should be noted that *backward-compatibility* is a misnomer in HTTP. There really is no such thing. The API version is a contract that includes the model. The convenience or ease by which a new version of a model can be converted to/from an old version of the model should be considered just that - convenience. It's easy to think that an additive change is backward-capable, but a server cannot guarantee that it is with clients. Striking the notion of *backwards-capable* in the context of HTTP will help you fall into the pit of success.
5. Using Open API (formerly known as Swagger) is likely the best option to integrate clients with any language. There are tools that can use the document to create clients into your preferred programming language. I don't have a specific recommendation for a Java library/framework on the server side, but there are several options.